# Need to assign dic to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have problems when I try to assign a dict to the df DataFrame,

```
df.loc[index,'count'] = dict()
```

as I get this error message:

```
Incompatible indexer with Series
```

To work around this problem, I can do this,

```
df.loc[index,'count'] = [dict()]
```

, but I don't like this solution since I have to resolve the list before getting the dictionary i.e.

```
a = (df.loc[index,'count'])[0]
```

How can I solve this situation in a more elegant way?

**EDIT1**

One way to replicate the whole code is as follow

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['count', 'aaa'])
d = dict()
df.loc[0, 'count'] = [d]; print('OK!'); 
df.loc[0, 'count'] = d
```

Output:

```
OK!
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-193-67bbd89f2c69>", line 4, in <module>
    df.loc[0, 'count'] = d

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 194, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 625, in _setitem_with_indexer
    value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 765, in _align_series
    raise ValueError('Incompatible indexer with Series')

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Comment: Try to share some data (or a small example), see: **[mcve]**

Comment: The more elegant way is not to include lists or `dicts` in a `DataFrame` records. Pandas is best suited for vectorized data and their operations, nesting data structures within it contradicts its purpose and you lose many of the features. I would advise against this.

Comment: so you want to replace certain items in your dataframe with data from a dictionary?  Can you give the data you are working with (for the dataframe and for the dictionary)?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want to achieve with dummy data?

Comment: with your example, you can do `df.loc[0] = [ d, None]` and then `df.loc[0, 'count']` is a `dict`, not a `list` with a `dict`.

Comment: Excellent comment @iDrwish...use pandas for data analysis not a middle stack container. OP does not explain the full picture either of *why* the need to store dicts. Hence, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @iDrwish how else would you implement this?

Comment: There is not a very obvious answer to this, you can use native python `list` to do the job, if you are working with `dict` objects, then opting for `json` might be beneficial. However, given that `pandas` is built on augmenting `np.array`, which is mainly designed to handle vectorized data formats.